# Vista - Office 2007 Microsoft Offfice Suite Service Pack 2 (SP2) fails to update: Code 80070663

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update, microsoft-office-2007

The auto-update has failed many times

There is about 650 MB of free disk space, and the update is about 300 MB.

When I use the auto-search interface, it sends me to search results that do not have an entry for the error message (who's idea was that, to create error messages and not put a solution on the help site?!).

Does anyone have experience with this error, or understand what the free-disk requirements are for a download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the size of the disks on this system to 40GB, and the auto-update ran successfully at night.

So, I can only suspect that this was related to running out of space while trying to do the upgrade, and that the update size does not reflect temporary space requirements.